# Find $\delta$ such that if $0 < \vert x - 2 \vert < \delta$, then $\vert f(x)-3 \vert < .2$

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

I'm looking for assistance with the following problem:

Find $\delta$ such that if $0 < \vert x - 2 \vert < \delta$, then $\vert f(x)-3 \vert < .2$ where $f(x)=x^2-1$.

My attempt:

We need $\delta$ such that $\vert f(x)-2 \vert < .2$. That is, we need $\vert x^2 - 1 - 3 \vert = \vert x^2 - 4 \vert = \vert x+2 \vert \cdot \vert x-2 \vert < .2$. We can control $\vert x - 2 \vert$ by $\delta$. Let us then restrict $x$ to the interval $(1,3)$. Thus $\vert x+2 \vert < 5$. Then we will let $\delta = \frac{.2}{5}$.

Now then, if $0 < \vert x - 2 \vert < \delta = \frac{.2}{5}$ then $\vert f(x)-3 \vert =  \vert x^2 - 4 \vert = \vert x+2 \vert \cdot \vert x-2 \vert < 5 \cdot \frac{.2}{5}=.2.$ $\Box$

Does this work for a valid delta? I'm basically taking the more general case where $\delta$ would be $\min(\frac{\epsilon}{5},1)$ and trying to fit it to this specific case.

Comment: Yes, added that.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, what is epsilon? I believe you want epsilon instead of 2 in your question.

Comment: Epsilon is given as 0.2.

Comment: Ah that explains all the dots you were putting.

Comment: Hint. If $|x-2|< \delta$ then $2-\delta < x < 2 + \delta$ and, so $4-\delta < x+2 < 4 + \delta$

Answer (score 1):

Since
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)-3|&=&|x^2-4|\\
&=&|x-2||(x-2)+4|\\
&\le& |x-2|(|x-2|+4)\\
&=&|x-2|^2+4|x-2| 
\end{eqnarray}
if we solve the inequality
$$
y^2+4y\le 0.2
$$
we get
$$
a\le y\le b,
$$
with
\begin{eqnarray}
a&=&-2-\sqrt{4.2}\approx-4.0494\\ 
b&=&-2+\sqrt{4.2}\approx0.0494\\ 
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, choosing $\delta \in (0,b)$, we have
$$
0<|x-2|<\delta \implies a<|x-2|<b \implies |f(x)-1|\le |x-2|^2+4|x-2|<0.2
$$

Answer (score 1):

The other solution is of course neat :-)

If $|x^2-4|<0.2$ then we have that $3.8<x^2<4.2$ that is either

1. $\sqrt{3.8}<x<\sqrt{4.2}$ or
2. $-\sqrt{4.2}<x<-\sqrt{3.8}$.

Consider case $1$. From here we get 
\begin{align}
-0.05064\sim\sqrt{3.8}-2&<x-2<\sqrt{4.2}-2\sim0.04939
\end{align}
Now if we want $-\delta<x-2<\delta$, then we can choose $\delta<\sqrt{4.2}-2$.

For case $2$ we have 
\begin{align}
-4.04939\sim-\sqrt{4.2}-2&<x-2<-\sqrt{3.8}-2\sim -3.94936
\end{align}
implying that $\delta$ shall be negative which is not possible.